# Which event in Kendo UI Grid, shall i use save the State of Grid

Tags: events, cookies, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to save State(paging, columns, groups, filters , etc.) of Kendo Grid.

I want to save the state object in cookies. 
Which event in Kendo UI Grid, shall i use to save the State of Grid.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to come across this jsbin in one of the Telerik Forums. This should probably help

http://jsbin.com/kuzehanihu/1/edit

Personally I feel you should try make use of the local storage for persisting. The Telerik demo demonstrates it:

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/persist-state

Comment: i have edit option also in my grid. When i use this procedure, my columns in grid (which are of dropdown list type when edit) are showing as number type rather than dropdownlist.